# Pygame не загружает картинку

Tags: python, pygame

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, pygame никак не хочет загружать картинку. Видается такая ошибка:

pygame.error: Couldn't open MainCharacter.kra
Помогите разобраться, буду очень благодарен!

Вот код:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (50, 170, 70)

STOP = 0
TOP = 1
motion = STOP

game = pygame.display.set_mode((750, 750))

while True:
    game.fill(GREEN)

    mp = pygame.image.load("MainCharacter.kra")
    mp_rect = mp.get_rect()
    game.blit(mp, mp_rect)

    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
        elif i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if i.key == pygame.K_w:
                motion = TOP

    pygame.display.update()

clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: что такое `"MainCharacter.kra"` ???

Comment: Вы уверены, что библиотека поддерживает такой формат картинок? https://docs.krita.org/en/tutorials/saving-for-the-web.html

Comment: S.Nick - это нарисованный персонаж

Comment: Вася - Сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Вы уверены, что этот файл лежит в одной папке с этим кодом?

Comment: @timur файл не обязан лежать в той же директории, что и код

Comment: @вася mp = pygame.image.load("MainCharacter.kra")  и как он найдёт его в другой директории ?

Comment: @Интик рабочая директория != директория с исходным кодом

Comment: Итак, спасибо за подсказку с директорией, ну и за то что нельзя использовать .kra, я уже все исправил, переместив файл в нужную деректорию, и изменил .kra, на .png. Спасибо всем!

Answer (score 1):

pygame не поддерживает расширение `kra`

Answer (score 0):

я засомневался в ответе @lisky

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (50, 170, 70)

STOP = 0
TOP = 1
motion = STOP

game = pygame.display.set_mode((750, 750))

while True:
    game.fill(GREEN)

    mp = pygame.image.load("Hen-800.kra")
    mp_rect = mp.get_rect()
    game.blit(mp, mp_rect)

    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
        elif i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if i.key == pygame.K_w:
                motion = TOP

    pygame.display.update()

clock.tick(FPS)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]